# How do I display an image locally in react using a local server?

Tags: html, reactjs, image, npm, create-react-app

I've seen a couple threads on displaying images in react, but they don't seem to be in line with what I need, here.

First of all, I started a project by using npx create-react-app, and then I used the npm start functionality provided by what was generated for me.

Now when I try to render an image tag, it seems like nothing works.  I can see in my debugger that the URL is coming through as I expect it, but I've tried things like:

```
./images/image.png
/images/image.png
images/image.png
src/images/image.png
localhost:3000/images/image.png
require("./images/image.png")
```

I've tried moving the image to the root folder and just setting the src to be "image.png", and I've tried just about every combination of file path names I could think of.  What was shown above was just a small sample.

For reference, my file structure has me working in a folder called src which contains a folder called images, which holds the image in question.  Visually, it looks like this:

```
> src/
  index.js
  > images/
    image.js
```

as well as some other irrelevant files, like the index.html.  I can get other stuff to render, just not this img tag, it's driving me crazy!  Thanks to whoever can help!

Comment: Move the images folder in the `> public/` folder, as that is where the dev version is served from.

Comment: Yes!  That was it!  That was the issue, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

How about wrap it inside bracket like :

```
<img src={"./path/to/image"} />
```

or import it first :

```
import img from "./path/to/img";

<img src={img} />
```

For example you're using this image inside index.js :

```
import img from "./images/image.png";

<img src={img} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers!  The first one actually isn't the problem, in the debugger, I'm seeing the strings under src that I'm expecting to see.

For the second answer, I actually want this string to be able to change based on the state of the component, but just for funsies, I tried importing a hard coded string.  It resulted in a "Module not found" error.